# Wer sagt "die" Nutella?

Tags: grammar

Im deutschsprachigen Raum wird "das" Nutella benutzt, aber wenn ich mich nicht irre, ist "die" Nutella eigentlich feminin. Meine Frage ist, sagt einer von euch die Nutella? Oder habt ihr es mal gehört?

Comment: Ich nehme solche Wörter überhaupt nicht in den Mund und sage *Nuss-Nougat-Creme.*

Comment: Ich sage "die".

Comment: Es ist der Nutella, es ist ja auch der Mozarella und beides ist aus Italien (Ferrero).

Comment: In Italien sagt man definitiv "la Nutella"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Der [Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/) hat zwischen Juli 2006 und Dezember 2007 unter anderem das [Nutella-Problem](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-4/f24a-g/) anhand einer Umfrage erörtert:

> [image: der/die/das Nutella - Verteilung]
>
> **"Nutella" (Genus) (Frage 24d)**
>
> Die Varianz zwischen den einzelnen Artikeln, mit denen Nutella (also die von einem Produktnamen übernommene Bezeichnung für einen süßen, kakaohaltigen Brotaufstrich) gebraucht wird, ist offenbar nicht in erster Linie geographisch bedingt. Im gesamten Sprachraum ist sowohl *das* als auch *die* gebräuchlich. *Der* findet sich hingegen fast nur im äußersten Westen Deutschlands sowie in Ostbelgien und Luxemburg. In Südtirol kennt man nur *die Nutella*; möglicherweise kommt hier der Einfluss des Italienischen zum Tragen, in dem Substantive auf -a in der Regel Feminina sind.

*Die* Nutella ist also durchaus verbreitet.

Comment: Endlich kommt mal wieder der Alltagsatlas :) Schön!

Answer (score 6):

**Nutella** ist ein geschützter Markennamen der Firma Ferrero. Nachdem es immer wieder zu Problemen mit dem Genus kommt, schreibt sogar der Hersteller in seinen FAQ:

> **Heißt es "der", "die" oder "das" nutella?**
>   nutella ist ein im Markenregister eingetragenes Fantasiewort, das in der Regel **ohne Artikel** verwendet wird. Es bleibt somit jedem selbst überlassen, welchen Artikel er vor nutella setzt. <sup>[FERRERO](http://www.ferrero.de/produkte/fragen.aspx?index=28)</sup>

Interessant in diesem Zusammenhang ist auch, dass nutella hier auch konsequent kleingeschrieben wird.

Das beantwortet die Frage aber in keinster Weise, erklärt aber, warum es hier keinen "richtigen" oder "falschen" Artikel geben kann (siehe auch [Zwiebelfisch zu diesem Thema](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-krieg-der-geschlechter-a-290172.html)).

Eine Google-Suche gibt uns etwa gleich viele Fundstellen für "die nutella" und "das nutella"; es werden also offenbar beide Formen gleich häufig benutzt. Das deckt sich mit meinem persönlichen Umfeld, wo ich beides hören kann:

> *"Wo ist denn das Nutella?"* – *"Reichst du mir bitte mal die Nutella?"*

"Die" wohlgemerkt in einer Gegend, in der man häufiger *"das Cola"* als *"die Cola"* sagt (Süddeutschland, Schwaben).

Comment: In keinster Weise?

Comment: @userunknown in keinster Weise, FERRERO drückt sich da nämlich ("kein Artikel" aber vielleicht doch ein Gechlecht?).

Comment: Sag bloß, wir haben noch keine Frage zu "keinster Weise" in German.SE. Dann wird's aber mal Zeit. Falls Du @userunknown und mir einen Gefallen tun willst, ändere es bitte in "keiner Weise" und vermeide in Zukunft Superlative bei nicht steigerbaren Wörtern.

Comment: Manchmal ist weniger als nichts eben mehr als alles ;)

Comment: Das war die einzigste richtige Pointe!

Answer (score 3):

Hinweis vorneweg: Ich bin Alemanne (Badener aus dem Südschwarzwald).

Für mich ist Nutella feminin, also verwende ich `Gibst du mir mal die Nutella`.

Aber da die Nutella in einem Glas ist, verwende ich meist `Gibst du mir mal das Nutellaglas?`.

Comment: Sollte es einmal in einem Schuh serviert werden, dann natürlich `Gibst du mir mal den Nutellaschuh`

Answer (score 1):

Ich glaube ich habe es schonmal gehört, aber eigentlich wird hier auch immer nur "das" benutzt. Laut duden.de ist "die Nutella" aber recht häufig:

> Häufig wird die weibliche Form die Nutella verwendet, wohl abgeleitet von der aus dem Italienischen stammenden femininen Endung -ella.

[Alle Gute zum Geburtstag!](http://www.duden.de/aktuelle_meldungen/alles-gute-zum-geburtstag-) auf duden.de.